# Redirect an Outgoing port using IPTables to an aliased IP

Tags: linux, iptables, port-forwarding

I'm working on a network where I need to set up a specific port forward and am struggling to figure out if IPTables can do it.

I have a server on an internal IP (192.168.XXX.1) routing through a firewall with a local IP of (192.168.XXX.254).  That firewall has an external IP on it's main interface and a virtual interface with a second IP.

What I want to do is forward all traffic on one PORT from the internal server through the firewall on the second IP, retaining all other traffic through the first IP.

Answer (score 0):

Try NAT

Something like this might work

```
/sbin/iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp -i ethX -d ${IP_ADDRESS} --dport ${someport} -j DNAT --to ${OTHER_IP_ADDRESS}:${otherport}
```